# How to fix error "argument of type (open: any) => boolean is not assignable to parameter of type boolean" using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to fix the error "argument of type (open: any) => boolean is not assignable to parameter of type boolean" using react and typescript

i have a method toggleDialogVisibility defined like below

```
export const useDialog() {
    const {setDialogVisibility} = React.useContext(DialogContext);
    return (
        const toggleDialogVisibility = (toggleValue: boolean) => {
            setDialogVisible(toggleValue);
        };
    );
}
```

and i am calling it in other component like below,

```
function Parent() {
    const {toggleDialogVisibility} = useDialog();
    return (
        <div onClick={() => toggleDialogVisibility(open => !open)} /> //getting error here
    );
}
```

i am not sure how to what type to be passed here. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: change `open => !open` in the `Parent` function to just `!open`.

Comment: Sorry that is incorrect, type the function `toggleDialogVisibility` to be `(toggleValue: (currentValue: boolean) => boolean)` and leave the rest as originally posted.

Answer (score -1):

The type of param function `toggleDialogVisibility` is boolean. You should send a boolean instead a callback function.

```
() => toggleDialogVisibility(!open)}
```

Answer (score -1):

send the toggle value as well not just the function this solved it for me, in the parent component:

```
 const [toggle, setToggle] = useState<boolean>(false);
   <EditForm setToggle={setToggle} open={toggle}/>
```

in the child compnent:

```
interface Props{
    open: boolean,
    setToggle: (toggle: boolean) => void
  }
  setToggle(!open);
```