# How to fix error "argument of type false is not assignable to (currentValue: boolean) => boolean" using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to fix the error "argument of type false is not assignable to (currentValue: boolean) => boolean using react and typescript.

i have a method toggleDialogVisibility defined like below

```
export const useDialog() {
    const {setDialogVisibility} = React.useContext(DialogContext);
    return ({
        const toggleDialogVisibility = (toggleValue: (currentValue: boolean) => boolean) => { //this is causing the error
            setDialogVisible(toggleValue);
        };
    } );
};
```

and i am calling it in two components like below,

```
function Parent() {
    const {toggleDialogVisibility} = useDialog();
    return (
        <div onClick={() => toggleDialogVisibility(open => !open)} />
    );
}

function AnotherComponent() {
    const {toggleDialogVisibility} = useDialog();
    const handle = () => {
        toggleDialogVisibility(false);  //error here
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to fix this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: i have edited my question. there was a typo in my code before. yes that works. but it gives error when i am using the same toggleDialogVisibility in other component (AnotherComponent)

Comment: So what happened to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63822492 ?

Comment: please compare my code with the one in this question. the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63822492 has mentioned only calling toggleDialogVisibility from parent component. and it works for the provided solution there. but now i have another component where i call toggleDialogVisibility(false) like so which throws error now.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
return (
        const toggleDialogVisibility = (toggleValue: boolean) => {
            setDialogVisible(toggleValue);
        };
    );
```

You think you are returning an *object with a function* but it is not the case.

## Fix

Return a function e.g.

```
return ({ 
    toggleDialogVisibility: (toggleValue: boolean) => {
        setDialogVisible(toggleValue);
    };
});
```

Comment: i have edited my question. there was a typo in my code. i fixed it now. could you please have a look at it. i think the problem is with the type i pass in definition of toggleDialogVisibility. but dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need useDialog

```
function Parent() {
    const {setDialogVisibility} = React.useContext(DialogContext);
    return (
        <div onClick={() => setDialogVisibility(open => !open)} /> //getting error here
    );
}
function AnotherComponent() {
    const {setDialogVisibility} = React.useContext(DialogContext);
    const handle = () => {
        setDialogVisibility(false);  //error here
    }
}
```

if really want, i prefer

```
export const useDialog() {
    const {setDialogVisibility} = React.useContext(DialogContext);
    return React.useCallback(()=> {
      setDialogVisibility(x=> !x)
    }, [setDialogVisibility])
};

function Parent() {
    const toggle = useDialog();
    return (
        <div onClick={toggle} /> //getting error here
    );
}
function AnotherComponent() {
    const toggle = useDialog();
    return <div onClick={toggle}>Close</div>
}
```